# Google Spreadsheets: duplicate date for 7 cells and then increment date by 7 days and repeat

Tags: google-sheets, autofill

My spreadsheet is to look like this:

10/1/2013    data
10/1/2013    data
10/1/2013    data
10/1/2013    data
10/1/2013    data
10/1/2013    data
10/1/2013    data
[space left for clarity]
10/8/2013    data
10/8/2013    data
10/8/2013    data
10/8/2013    data
10/8/2013    data
10/8/2013    data
10/8/2013    data

I know how to auto-fill the dates so that each subsequent cell is 7 days after the previous, ie:

10/1/2013
10/8/2013
10/15/2013
etc.

But I need exactly 7 cells to carry an identical date before moving on. Any idea how to do this? I'm looking at the cell.setFormula method at the moment for clues.

Cheers,
Mig

Answer (score 1):

To start with a simple solution... why not put the following formula cell A8??

It would take a little modification of the formula for you to copy this formula into cells A2 through A7 instead of hardcoding that first set of 7 rows. But this should get you started.

=if(A7=A1,A7+7,A7)